# Interacting with cmd prompt during loop

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

I'm trying to open the command prompt in a loop from a Python script, and within the command prompt 1.) type to change directory and 2.) type a command. Once the command is entered and running, I'll need to wait for it to finish before moving to the next part of the script, but haven't got that far.

I have the following, which I hope can open cmd and communicate.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('cmd', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

process.communicate(b'cd /target/directory')
process.communicate(b'run.bat')
```

Am I on the right path, and how can I make the script wait until the command has finished then close?

*Edit:
I have a run.bat file within a directory, and would like to run it in the command prompt within its specific directory. I've tried running the .bat file by itself but haven't been successful. I have a cmd shortcut that opens the prompt in the same directory as run.bat, and entering 'run.bat' of course works. As this has been the only thing that worked so far, I'm trying to replicate these steps in a Python script.

Comment: There's likely no reason to use `cmd` to do those two things because the can both be done more directly other ways. Why are you trying to do them this way?

Comment: Apart from that, you should be able to directly open a cmd.exe process within the required working directory and with one or more commands as arguments. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65295787/edit), to explain exactly what it is you're intending doing, so that answers can be given within the correct context.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the command to finish then exit you can simply add this instead of the second communicate

```
process.communicate(b'run.bat && exit 0')
```

This will run the `run.bat` file then after it is finished exit with code 0